# How do I write a schema to validate a YAML element as either a string OR a list of strings

Tags: yaml, jsonschema

I'm trying to write a schema to validate YAML where both of these are valid:

```
who:
  vocals: roger
```

```
who:
  vocals:
    - roger
    - pete
```

`vocals` can be either a single string or a list of strings.

This works for the first,

```
 "vocals": {
     "type": "string"
 },
```

And this works for the second,

```
 "vocals": {
     "type": "array",
     "uniqueItems": true,
     "items": {
       "type": "string"
     }
  },
```

But I can't work out how to combine them, since it doesn't seem like I can use `anyOf` in the context of property types.

Any pointers welcome, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `oneOf` to create both branches of valid schemas

```yaml
properties:
  who:
    properties:
      vocals:
        oneOf:
          - type: array
            uniqueItems: true
            items:
              type: string
          - type: string
```

Comment: Well, I was making that a whole lot more complicated than it had to be.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be [oneOf](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#id7) the keyword you want to use? Just put both of your definitions for vocals as items in the array of `oneOf` schemas.